# How to Filter records with some column with similar value and some not

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table A

```
Table A

ID       Date        Price
123      4/1/2015    300
123      4/1/2015    500
456      4/1/2015    200
456      5/1/2015    200
789      6/1/2015    300
368      NULL        700
```

Scenario: I want to pull all those records where date is same but price is not same:

for example:

```
ID       Date        Price
123      4/1/2015    300
123      4/1/2015    500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
join
(
  select id
  from your_table
  group by id, date
  having count(distinct price) > 1
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

One method uses analytic functinos:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(price) over (partition by id, date) as minprice,
             max(price) over (partition by id, date) as maxprice
      from t
     ) t
where minprice <> maxprice;
```

Another uses a simple `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.date = t.date);
```

Both of these methods assume that `date` has no time component.  If it does, then use `trunc(date)` or similar logic.